# Python (2.7): Error Handling in __init__ with Sensitive Information

Tags: python, exception, password-protection, pexpect

I am trying to find a good way to handle errors in `__init__()` without revealing sensitive data in a traceback.

I have a class based on pxssh and I execute my connection in `__init__()`.
The purpose is to initialize an object for sending CLI commands to a child.

```
class MyClass(pxssh.pxssh):
    def __init__(self, credentials):
    .
    .
    .
    try:
        self.connect(credentials)
    except Exception as e:
        stderr.write('Error: %s\n' % str(e)
        exit(1)
```

This was fine for testing, but this class is meant to be used by other code and I don't want to go killing the caller with `exit(1)`.

I would use `raise` instead of `exit(1)`, but the trouble is that `credentials` is a dictionary including a password and some other sensitive connection information. I don't want to see it dumped in a traceback if the caller just raises whatever exceptions I throw.

What would be the best way to handle this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're worried about the traceback, why not `raise` a fresh error that doesn't contain anything from `credentials`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe probably because they want to `raise` from `__init__`, and no matter what error is raised, the traceback so generated will include a reference to the frame where `__init__` ran (including the `credentials` dictionary)

Comment: @thepaul oh, I see. Well if the OP is worried about in-process attacks, as you comment below, there's not much to be done!

Comment: I think that protecting in-process attacks are outside the scope of what I'm doing. Keeping the credentials out of a traceback meets my needs well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the exception, clear the sensitive information, then re-raise:

```
class MyClass(pxssh.pxssh):
    def __init__(self, credentials):
        # ...
        try:
            self.connect(credentials)
        except Exception as e:
            credentials.clear()
            raise
```

This empties the `credentials` dictionary altogether; any other references to it will also show it is now empty. Any traceback formatter that includes values of locals will show an empty dictionary instead.

However, note that this cannot protect you from disclosure, as any malicious code can simply install a [`sys.settrace()` hook](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) and access `credentials` any time it exists before the exception occurs.

Or the attacker could simply replace `MyClass.__init__` with a wrapper that captures and stores the `credentials` value before calling the original version. The same applies to the `MyClass.connect()` method.

Python's dynamic nature makes it entirely unsuitable to try and protect your values from an attacker that is *already* part of your process.

Comment: Quite right; if you have any untrusted code running in the same process, it's going to be essentially impossible to guard against it accessing the credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and extra security thoughts.